# write processed files in spark streaming

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using Spark streaming (in java) to consume messages from Kafka. I have done some processing on top of the rdd. Now, I should write this processed information (string) to a file on s3. How do I achieve this?

```
directKafkaStream.map(message -> recordInjection.invert(message._2).get()).foreachRDD(rdd -> {
                rdd.foreach(record -> {
  // processing each record, storing the processed info in a string.
  // write each processed record (string) to s3
  });
});
```

Comment: guess the only way is to form an rdd using map function and then write to s3.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use RDD.saveAsTextFile("s3a://bucket/path/file.avro"), though you may find yourself creating many, many small files.

Comment: Steve, I am extracting some fields out of my RDD, and that's what I want to save to S3. Since I can only save RDDs, there is no way I am able to save those fields directly.